# Trying to put AsyncStorage.getItem() inside async/await try/catch nest but returning unexpected stuff

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I have this on React-Native, basically I successfully saved some stuff using `AsyncStorage` from the LoginScreen. Now I'm trying to access those variables on my HomeScreen using `AsyncStorage.getItem`

```
const userdata = async () => { 
        try {
            return await AsyncStorage.getItem("user_nicename")      
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    console.log(userdata)
    //returns  { ƒ _callee() {
    //return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.async(function _callee$(_context) {
    //    while (1) {
    //      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {....
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems to be very straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

userdata is an async function. Try this:

```
console.log(await userdata())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you are going wrong about this

- You are logging the function without calling, if you want to see the function evaluated, you have to call it by adding parenthesis for example in your case it would `userdata()`
- You are calling an asynchronous function as though it was a synchronous function. Your code was written asynchronously so you need to call it asynchronously as well.
- As per js convention for naming identifier, turn `userdata` to `userData`

For your solution, you will need to call your function, `userdata` in a promise-based function either async-await or .then or in a callback function. I am suggesting two ways to improve your code.

Method 1: Using .then()

```js
// in home screen
userdata()
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Method 2: using async-await
in your home screen

```js
// home screen
const getUserData = async () => {
   try {
     console.log(await userdata());
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
};

// then call the function
getUserData()
```